# geth : Unable to fully sync to Rinkeby

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, ethereumjs, rinkeby

I am trying to synchronise geth with Rinkeby node but when around 100 or so block left, it keep on dropping the peer and doesnot sync fully with the test net below are the screenshot for the same.

[image: getherror]

[image: blocksync]

Comment: I have the same issue. What geth version are you on?